# How to run prev/next button within looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have found below code for a loop popup. It is worked for me. After, I added code for automatically expire `XML` node. When the code met the expire node, popups are stop looping. How can I implement the code.

Here is the code:-

data.xml

```
<cd expires="30/09/2018">
  <head>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</head>
  <image>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg</image>
</cd>

<cd expires="10/09/2018">
  <head>posuere lacus in, accumsan nulla.</head>
  <image>https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/SpMAAOSwceNZXpSZ/s-l300.jpg</image>
</cd>
```

To loop popup, I used below code

```
let nextIdx = idx + 1;
let prevIdx = idx - 1;
//to make cyclic
nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;
```

To expire XML element, I used below code

```
let expireArray = $(this).attr('expires').split('/');
        const expireDate = `${expireArray[2]}${expireArray[1]}${expireArray[0]}`;
        const now = new Date(),
            nowDate = `${now.getFullYear()}${(now.getMonth()+1) <10 ? '0'+(now.getMonth()+1): (now.getMonth()+1)}${now.getDate()}`;

        if (nowDate > expireDate) {
            return;
        }  

  //..........Please check plunker code
```

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GmYtTezOO8Kr1rS2?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we navigate to element, that was filtered by `nowDate > expireDate` - `popups are stop looping`.

`prevIdx/nextIdx/total` - should be calculated from `filtered` elements.

```
xml = $(xml).children();

const filteredChildren = $(xml).children()
.filter(function (el){
    /* CODE */
    return nowDate <= expireDate; 
    })

let total = filteredChildren.length;

filteredChildren.each(function (idx) {        
    let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
    let nextIdx = idx + 1;
    let prevIdx = idx - 1;
    //to make cyclic
    nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
    prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total -1) : prevIdx;

    /* CODE */
}
```

[Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/VfWT5f5zztlOsBaz?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Previous question was answered, if you have something more - please ask another question